# Calculating and assigning value in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can anyone please explain this statement:-

```
value=$(seq -w -s '' $index $(($index + 100000)));
```

What is the function of `-w`, `-s` and `''` ?

This is the code fraction where it is used:

```
for index in $(seq 1000); do
value=$(seq -w -s '' $index $(($index + 100000)))
eval array$index=$value
done
```

Comment: All of this would have been answered by `seq --help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `-w` is for padding. So `1` is displayed as `01`(as max value is of 2
  digits).
- `-s` is separator, so `-s ' '` means separate output by `'
  '`. Using `-s ''` will not use any separator, so it will displayed as
  one long number.

.

```
bash-4.2$ seq -w -s ' ' 1 10
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

bash-4.2$ seq -w -s '' 1 10
01020304050607080910
```

Run `man` or `--help` page for any command for details.

```
bash-4.2$ seq --help
Usage: seq [OPTION]... LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
Print numbers from FIRST to LAST, in steps of INCREMENT.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -f, --format=FORMAT      use printf style floating-point FORMAT
  -s, --separator=STRING   use STRING to separate numbers (default: \n)
  -w, --equal-width        equalize width by padding with leading zeroes
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```